# Apply ng-blur functions return to ng-modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i have 2 input fields named data1 and data2. I have assigned a ng-blur function to it. ITs a common function for both input fields. Now i need to use this function and use it for the 2 input fields.

```
<input ng-model="data1" ng-blur="checkAndApplySign(data1, false);">
<input ng-model="data2" ng-blur"checkAndApplySign(data2, true);">
```

I am using the below function. if toNegative is set to false at the HTML, we should get all positve values returned. if it is set to true, all negative values

```
$scope.checkAndApplySign = function (value, toNegative) {
    return (toNegative ? -1 : 1) * Math.abs(value);        
};
```

The problem with this is that the return function doesnot assign the values back to the input field. how do i assign it back to input field ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but my best guess is that, assuming your models are objects, they will be passed to the function as references. Knowing this, you should just be able to assign the value directly to the input value and its relationship with the input via ng-model should update the input value.

```
$scope.checkAndApplySign = function (value, toNegative) {
    value = (toNegative ? -1 : 1) * Math.abs(value);        
};
```

Comment: i tried this thing too. here, value is the value coming from UI. i.e. 23 for example. It doesnot indicate that 23 should be assigned to data1 or data2.. tats where my binding is not working

Comment: Well I guess you could make a directive to handle this, so you can directly update the view value with ngModelController.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

`$setViewValue(value, trigger)`